# Change Terminal's background with a command

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, wallpaper

Is there a command via which I can change the Terminal's background instead of doing so through the `Edit -> Profile -> Edit -> Background` pulldown?

Comment: It depends on your terminal emulator.

Comment: gnome terminal 3.6.2

Comment: Best guess: you can't. Maybe you can modify your profile settings in `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/`, but I don't think there's any way to make Gnome Terminal reload preferences on-the-fly. The reason I'm making a comment with a "guess" instead is because, unfortunately, Gnome Terminal no longer supports background images since version 3.8, so I can't even test it to see if what you're trying to do is at all possible.

Comment: ` gconftool-2 --type string  --set  /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/...   ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below and see if it suits your needs. In my Gnome it changes the background ***color*** in real time.

Note that it assumes you want the original profile; pick the profile you prefer from `dconf dump / |grep legacy/profiles:/ |sed -r 's/^\[|\]$//g'` and use `profile=your_preferred_profile` instead of the first line below.

```
profile="$(dconf dump / |grep legacy/profiles:/ |sed -r 's/^\[|\]$//g' |head -n1)"
dconf write /$profile/background-color "'rgb(50,50,50)'"
dconf write /$profile/foreground-color "'rgb(170,170,170)'"
dconf write /$profile/use-theme-colors false
```